# Laravel : Get id of logged user

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using **Laravel Passport** to manage the authentification of the user.
When a user is logged, in the **localstorage** of the browser I have the following info :

```
    {
        "user": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "test",
            "email": "test@gmail.com",
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "created_at": "2021-05-08T06:57:27.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-05-08T06:57:27.000000Z"
        },
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6Ijk2MjkxN2YyYzAwZjM5NmMwMTAzYzRjYTYwODk1YmYxMzY1MDE5OGQ1ZDQ5ZDJjNThlYzc0YmRkMzg2ZTk3MTE3MWE3ZWRjNjMyNjkwNjlhIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiOTYyOTE3ZjJjMDBmMzk2YzAxMDNjNGNhNjA4OTViZjEzNjUwMTk4ZDVkNDlkMmM1OGVjNzRiZGQzODZlOTcxMTcxYTdlZGM2MzI2OTA2OWEiLCJpYXQiOjE2MjA0Njg0MjQsIm5iZiI6MTYyMDQ2ODQyNCwiZXhwIj"
}
```

My `web.php`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\Profile;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/customize/{id}', function ($id) {
   
    if (
        User::where('id', Auth::id())->whereHas('profile', function ($query) use ($id) {
            return $query->where('id', $id);
        })
        ->exists()
    )  {
        return true;
      }      
      return false;
});
```

If I replace `Auth::id()` with a hardcoded value such as `4` it works.

**How can I get the id of the current logged user ?**

Edit: What I tried so far :

```
auth()->guard('api')->user()
Auth::id()
Auth::user()->id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may only need to reference `Auth::user()->id` where you have now `Auth::id()`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\Profile;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/customize/{id}', function ($id) {
   
    if (
        User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->whereHas('profile', function ($query) use ($id) {
            return $query->where('id', $id);
        })
        ->exists()
    )  {
        return true;
      }      
      return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm getting `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`.

Comment: @AlyaKra `Auth::user()` is returning an empty object in this case. Are you using `Sentry` ? If so try `Sentry::getUser()->id`

Comment: I see. No I don't think I'm using `Sentry`. I'm using only Laravel Passport for tokens.